# How to add underline to a label?

Tags: silverlight

I have a System.Windows.Controls.Label in my xaml and I'm trying to add an underline style.  I can't seem to figure out what to add to my Style to make it underline.  When I google for this problem, I only see TextBox solutions.  Is that the only way to get an underline?

XAML:

```
<sdk:Label Content="Show Data in Grid" Name="lblShowGridData" Style="{StaticResource UnderlineLabel}"/>
```

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="UnderlineLabel" TargetType="sdk:Label">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Label` is a `ContentControl`, so you can stick a `TextBlock` with underlining inside it:

```
    <sdk:Label>
        <TextBlock Text="This is underlined" TextDecorations="Underline" />
    </sdk:Label>
```